# ActivePivot: Any code to convert the CellSetDTO object to csv, excel or other formats?

Tags: activepivot

I am new to activePivot.  We invoked a mdx query and got a CellSetDTO back.  Is there any library code available to convert this CellSetDTO object to CSV, Excel, or other type of formats?

I am looking at the javadoc from quartetfs on the CellSetDTO class but the javaDoc has no description.  Alternatively, I can write my own code to produce the CSV but since I am new to this and there is no description on the javaDoc, it is a bit hard to start.

Any pointer to any documentation is appreciated.

Thank you,
Grace

Answer (score 1):

you can use the sample that you can find in the sandbox project, see the CellSetPrinter class, set the CellSetDTO  in the constructor arg.
See the CellSetPrinter  class:

```
public class CellSetPrinter {

protected final CellSetDTO cellSet;

protected final AxisDTO slicer;

protected final List<AxisDTO> axes;

protected final List<CellDTO> cells;

public CellSetPrinter(CellSetDTO cellSet) {
    this.cellSet = cellSet;
    this.axes = cellSet.getAxes().getAxis();
    this.slicer = cellSet.getSlicerAxis();
    this.cells = cellSet.getCells().getCell();
}

/**
 * Compute axis positions from the cell ordinal with the classic formula:
 * <ul>
 * <li>(x0, x1, x2) -> x0 + x1 * n0 + x2 * n1 * n2
 * <li>ordinal -> (ordinal % n0, (ordinal / n0) % n1, (ordinal / (n0*n1)) % n2)
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param ordinal
 * @return tuple expressed by coordinates
 */
protected List<String> getTuple(int ordinal) {
    List<String> tuple = new ArrayList<>();

    // Lookup positions on axes
    final int[] axisCoordinates = new int[axes.size()];

    int coeff = 1;
    for(int a = 0; a < axisCoordinates.length; a++) {
        int positionCount = axes.get(a).getPositions().getPosition().size();
        axisCoordinates[a] = (ordinal / coeff) % positionCount;
        coeff *= positionCount;
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < axisCoordinates.length; a++) {
        AxisPositionDTO position = axes.get(a).getPositions().getPosition().get(axisCoordinates[a]);
        for(MemberDTO member : position.getMembers().getMember()) {
            for(String pathElement : member.getPath().getItems().getItem()) {
                if(!"AllMember".equals(pathElement)) {
                    tuple.add(pathElement);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Append slicer content
    for(AxisPositionDTO position : slicer.getPositions().getPosition()) {
        for(MemberDTO member : position.getMembers().getMember()) {
            for(String pathElement : member.getPath().getItems().getItem()) {
                if(!"AllMember".equals(pathElement)) {
                    tuple.add(pathElement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tuple;
}

public void print(PrintStream out) {
    for(CellDTO cell : cells) {
        System.out.println(getTuple(cell.getOrdinal()) + " " + cell.getFormattedValue());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tuxmobil.  This is helpful.  I notice there are two cellDTO classes and both of which are very similar.  com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.dto.CellDTO and com.quartetfs.webservices.CellDTO classes.  I am not sure why there are two such similar classes.  I have the dto.CellDTO object.  When you refer to the sample, could you point me to which package?

Comment: add the following classes in the import:import com.quartetfs.webservices.AxisDTO;
import com.quartetfs.webservices.AxisPositionDTO;
import com.quartetfs.webservices.CellDTO;
import com.quartetfs.webservices.CellSetDTO;
import com.quartetfs.webservices.MemberDTO;